# Homebrew keep showing warning to set PATH on OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh, zshrc

I am on Mac OSX 10.11 after running

```
brew doctor
```

And there is a warning in my terminal.

```
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

After I fixed this PATH in my `.zshrc` file, I run `brew doctor` again,
this error is still remain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What my `.zshrc` file now looks like:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

I finally solved this problem by **restarting** my terminal and run `brew doctor` again.
Warnings disappear!

Comment: Thanks for the hint to restart terminal! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this problem : delete all "unbound" * in /usr/local/sbin;
Then cakebrew and homebrew doctors are OK
Have a nice day